# if else in angular2 template syntax

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Angular2..why and how?

How do I execute the below if condition in angular2

```
    <td *ngFor="let val of rows;let j=index">
            IF J==0
                 <label>{{val}}</label>
            ELSE:
               <label style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;padding-top: 5px">{{val}}</label>

</td>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can use the [*ngIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html#!#ngIfElse-anchor) structural directive with the if-else syntax to achieve this result.

```html
<label *ngIf="j === 0; else elseBlock">{{val}}</label>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <label style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;padding-top: 5px">{{val}}</label>
</ng-template>
```

Another option is to use two `*ngIf` blocks and invert the conditional, like so:

```html
<label *ngIf="j === 0">{{val}}</label>
<label *ngIf="j !== 0" style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;padding-top:5px">{{val}}</label>
```

Comment: I believe `*ngIf="j === 0; else elseBlock"` is an Angular4 feature, not working in Angular 2 right? Anyway, that would be the best approach in my opinion: 1. Upgrade to Angular 4. 2. Apply this code.

Comment: That is correct. I was not sure which version of Angular OP was using so I provided the answer for the current version of the framework and a fall back. I am leery of the `angular2-template` tag meaning actually template syntax for version 2.X as the description references `Angular2` which is not the correct name of the framework.

Comment: Indeed. *"Angular 2"* doesn't exist no more, now is just **Angular** for versions 2+, and AngularJs for versions 1.x. :D

Answer (score 10):

If you plan on upgrading to Angular 4, you could use the new if / else in template that includes this version. Example:

```
<div *ngIf="someCondition; else falsyTemplate">
  <h1>Condition Passed!</h1>
</div>

<ng-template #falsyTemplate>
  <h1>Condition Failed!</h1>
</ng-template>
```

Check the following useful links:

- http://angularjs.blogspot.it/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html
- http://tylerscode.com/2017/03/angular-4-ngifelse/
- https://medium.com/aviabird/ngif-else-lands-in-angular-2-0-a242940e54ff

I would personally recommend upgrading to Angular 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in Angular 2 by using the `<ng-container>` element. In your example it should be something like this:

```
<td *ngFor="let val of rows;let j=index">
    <ng-container *ngIf="J==0">
        <label>{{val}}</label>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="J!=0">
        <label style="color:#000000;font-size:12px;padding-top: 5px">{{val}}
</label>
    </ng-container>
</td>
```

You can find more information in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue.